# Image rotation, falsify image Histograms

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv, image-processing

I got that function that, by giving it an integer value, it rotate my image (I'm using OpenCV to store that object).

Here's my rotation function code:

```cpp
float rads = angle*3.1415926/180.0;
float _cos = cos(-rads);
float _sin = sin(-rads);
float xcenter = (float)(src.cols)/2.0;
float ycenter = (float)(src.rows)/2.0;

for(int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++) {
        int x = ycenter + ((float)(i)-ycenter)*_cos - ((float)(j)-xcenter)*_sin;
        int y = xcenter + ((float)(i)-ycenter)*_sin + ((float)(j)-xcenter)*_cos;
        if (x >= 0 && x < src.rows && y >= 0 && y < src.cols) {
            dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i ,j) = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y);
        } else
            dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i ,j) = NULL;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the last line set a `NULL` value to the 'empty' pixels, and that's the results:

[image]

as you can see, the Histogram in the upper right corner, as now I got lots of Black Pixels, is not reliable anymore, as I rotate my image, the histogram should remain like:

[image]

here's my code for calculating the 3 Histograms:

```cpp
int k = 0, r = 255, g = 255, b = 255;
switch (channel){ 
    case 0:
        k = 0; r = 255; g = 0; b = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        k = 1; r = 0; g = 255; b = 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        k = 2; r = 0; g = 0; b = 255;
        break;
}

int hist[256];
for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    hist[i] = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
        hist[(int)img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[k]]++;

int hist_w = 299;
int hist_h = 69;
int bin_w = cvRound((double) hist_w/256);

cv::Mat histImage(hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(50, 50, 50));

int max = hist[0];

for(int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
    if(max < hist[i])
        max = hist[i];

for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        hist[i] = ((double)hist[i]/max)*histImage.rows;

for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    line(histImage, cv::Point(bin_w*(i), hist_h), cv::Point(bin_w*(i), hist_h - hist[i]), cv::Scalar(r,g,b), 1, 8, 0);

return histImage;
```

does anybody know how can I fix that?

Comment: Unless you want to ignore any pixel that is 100% black, the only way to achieve this without knowing and accounting for the image's rotation would be to add an alpha channel into your image data any exclude any transparent pixels from being counted.

Comment: @paddy thank! that's exactly what I was thinking about, making a kind of 'mask'.
But starting from scratch, I don't know how to implement it, do you have any kind of examples?

Comment: Well, just as a thought, does opencv have a `Vec4b`?  Use channel 4 as the alpha.

Comment: @paddy so I have to implement that mask in the 'calculateHist' function I guess?

Comment: what part of this are you having trouble understanding?  an RGBA image has 4 channels.  you treat the alpha channel just like the color channels.  if a pixel is solid it has alpha 255.  if it's transparent it has alpha 0.  when you rotate the image, you are rotating 4-channel pixels into a new transparent image (i.e. all zeroes).  when you compute the histogram you ignore any pixels with alpha 0.  or if this is too confusing, you could just take my first suggestion instead and ignore any pixels that are (0,0,0).

Comment: @paddy thanks paddy, I now made it work, I was missing the conversion from RGB to RGBA channel, if you put  the first comment as answer I'm going to flag it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a little weird that you consciously add black pixels to the image and complain that this modifies the histogram! Please note that the new histograms are just… right.

This said, you will obtain the histogram of the non-black parts of the image by clearing the 0 bins in the three channels.

If for some reason you want to avoid those black areas without perturbing the initial histogram too much, and option is to fill them with pixels sampled *randomly* from the initial image. The image will be ugly, but the histogram safe.

Comment: As I was using Vec3b access, I thought the only way to make them 'not related to the image' was make them black, filling with 0 as I wrote.
Now I fixed it, just by converting the RGB to RGBA, and I'm able to set the alpha as transparent.